# $w''(z)-\frac{2}{z}w'(z)+w(z)=0$ linearly independent solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am solving this eq: $$w''(z)-\frac{2}{z}w'(z)+w(z)=0$$ using the Frobenius methodology. I found two roots $$w_1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^kk!(-\frac{1}{2})_k} z^{2k}  ,w_2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^kk!(\frac{5}{2})_k}z^{2k+3} $$ where $(a)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Now i want to proove that these two are linearly independent. However when i take their Wronskian it feels impossible to do these calculations. Am i missing something or maybe my solutions are miscalculated??

Comment: How did you find thses.?

Comment: Like i said with the frobenius method i substut: $w=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}C_kz^k.$

Comment: and the second with.?

Comment: the indicial equation has two solutions for λ.

Comment: i forgot up there the power of z is not k it is λ+k

Comment: the indicial equation ensures that two answers are linearly independent. But I have not found a reference yet.